# Выделение пояснения тире

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли так расставить тире? И как это можно аргументировать? Приложения ведь здесь нету?

Особенность рынка – на что мы обратили внимание – это наличие во всех спецификациях самых разных типов и видов арматуры.

Answer (score 2):

В корявых фразах пунктуация расставляется с трудом...
На ЧТО вы обратили внимание? На особенность? Или на наличие?

Особенность рынка, на которую мы обратили внимание, – наличие...

Хотя бы так. И то плоховато.